# Fitting data with predefined function python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

Could you please help with such task.
I have some data. I know that data must be fitted with some predefiened equation for example like y=(1-x/1+x).
I know that in Origin there is a possility to do that. Could it be done with
with scikit-learn or any other package ? When yes, could you pleas advise package and exact function.
Many thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using the Scikit Learn package, there are various models you can try. You can check these out, for example, they show how to fit a curve using various models.

[Curve Fitting with Bayesian Ridge Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_bayesian_ridge_curvefit.html)

[Polynomial interpolation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html)

[Validation curves: plotting scores to evaluate models](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html)

***OR***

You can also use ***Neural Networks*** to fit a curve pretty easily using frameworks like ***Tensorflow***/***PyTorch***. Below I've given an example of fitting a curve using ***PyTorch***.

#### PyTorch Curve Fitting (Function - Sin(2πx))

```
import random
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
import numpy as np

# Generating data, that is X and Y values for the model to train on
X = torch.unsqueeze(torch.linspace(-1, 1, 100), dim=1).to(device)  # x-axis values
y = (1-X/(1+X)) + torch.rand(X.size()) # adding a bit noise to the actual curve Sin(2πx), as real world is noisy and need our model to generalize

# some hyperparameters and global vars
seed = 1
random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
N = 1000  # num_samples_per_class
D = 1  # dimensions
C = 1  # num_classes
H = 200  # num_hidden_units
learning_rate = 1e-2  # How big of a step the model should take towards solution *very important parameter for neural networks
lambda_l2 = 1e-5  # Regularizes the network


# Bulding the model
# nn package to create our linear model
# each Linear module has a weight and bias
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(D, H),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(H, C)
)

# nn package also has different loss functions.
# we use MSE loss for our regression task
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()

# we use the optim package to apply
# stochastic gradient descent for our parameter updates
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=lambda_l2) # built-in L2

# Training
for t in range(2000):
    
    # Feed forward to get the logits
    y_pred = model(X)
    
    # Compute the loss (MSE)
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
    print("[EPOCH]: %i, [LOSS or MSE]: %.6f" % (t, loss.item()))
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    
    # zero the gradients before running
    # the backward pass.
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    # Backward pass to compute the gradient
    # of loss w.r.t our learnable params. 
    loss.backward()
    
    # Update params
    optimizer.step()

# After 2000 epochs/iterations of training
# Output: [EPOCH]: 1999, [LOSS or MSE]: 0.062801
```

#### Generated data from the function Sin(2πx) (with some noise added)

[image: Generated data]

#### Fitted curve by our neural network model with ~ 6% error

[image: Fitted Curve]

---

***Note: If you're unfamiliar with PyTorch you can just simply change X, Y value in the above code with your specification and it should work just fine. You can try different learning rates, activation (such as a hyperbolic tangent function), etc. for better results.***

Comment: great! If it helped you or answered your question, consider selecting it as the answer so that others find it useful as well. Thanks